# Найти произведение двух чисел, не превышающих 10^9

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Задача: найти произведение двух чисел, не превышающих 10^9.

```
int main()
{

long int a,b;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("product.in");
    fin >> a >>b;
    fin.close();

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("product.out");
    fout << (a*b);
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

*Выдает ошибку в тесте при проверке.*

Comment: А какую именно ошибку выдаёт, вы предлагаете нам угадать самостоятельно?

Может, файла нету, а может, `10^18` не помещается в `long int` на тестовой системе. А может, нет `#include` и `namespace std`.

Comment: А может вообще в тесте ошибка? )

На каком примере спотыкается? Там, может, числа большие 10^9.

Comment: @VladD, @BOPOH, ошибки в тесте нет (на codeferces), ошибку выдает на 7-м тесте, больше информации нет. Думаю, что действительно 10^18 не помещается, но ведь нету, вроде, еще большего для целочисленного.

Comment: @lextor: Ну так в этом и может быть нетривиальность задания. Попробуйте `static_assert`, проверяющий размер `long int`. (Надеюсь, сайт выдаст вам ошибки компиляции.) Если проблема именно в этом, организуйте длинную арифметику вручную.

Comment: Эм... А [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)?

10^9 * 10^9 - 2 147 483 647 = 999999997852516353

Может быть, стоит unsigned long long стоит попробовать?

UPD: ну или long long

Comment: Ну, переполнение всегда возможно...

Просто проверяйте результат умножения делением.

      int p = a * b, c = p / (b ? b : 1);
      if (c != a) 
         cerr << "Overflow !!! " << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << '\n';
      else {
        .... // делаем с p, что подразумевали
      }

Comment: Если еще интересно...

-- 

На самом деле по условию задачи  не важен результат умножения (по крайней мере, если он превышает 10^9), поэтому для решения достаточно даже типа `int` (32 разряда).

В самом деле, если знак у `a` и `b` разный, то в любом случае (было переполнение или нет) произведение < 0 (значит и меньше 10^9). 

Т.о. достаточно вычислять только:

     int p = a * b;
     int ovflow =  (a && b) ? (p / a) != b : 0;
     int less =  (((a > 0 && b < 0) || (a < 0 && b > 0)) ||
                  (p < 1000000000 & !ovflow));

Comment: @avp: Хм. http://ideone.com/zDYOx1

Comment: @VladD, все правильно, 

     signed int a = 64 * 256 * 16;
     signed int b = -3 * 256 * 16;
     signed int product = a * b;

переполнение.

Очевидная, но не написанная в комментарии строчка

      
    printf ("(int) (%d * %d = %d) %s less then 10^9\n", 
            a, b, p, less ? "" : "NOT");


печатает

     (int) (262144 * -12288 = 1073741824)  less then 10^9

На мой взгляд, это верно.

--

Ну, возможно, автору стоит получше анализировать ситуацию и печатать что-то вроде:

*"ВНИМАНИЕ! Было зафиксировано переполнение, цифры в результате не соответствуют правильному ответу".*